# How can I make bundle in my project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-bundle-plugin

I Build a multi module project having name **ThreadPool-Maven**

**ThreadPool-Maven**  contains two projects **ThreadPool-Implementation** and **ThreadPool-Evaluator**.

Both are interdependent, ThreadPool-Evaluator project are dependendent on ThreadPool-Implementation project.

**ThreadPool-Implementation** contains three java files.

1. ThreadPool.java
2. WorkerThreadPool.java
3. Done.java

**ThreadPool-Evaluator** contains two java files.

1. TestThreadPool.java
2. TestWorkerThread.java

These are my work till now. Now I want to build a bundle of **ThreadPool-Implementation** and **ThreadPool-Evaluator** and these bundles are used by **ThreadPool-Maven** to perform same task.
Help me to do that.

**POMS** are as follows:-

**ThreadPool-Maven** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz.intern.multiple_project</groupId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>ThreadPool-Maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Simple Parent Project ThreadPool-Maven</name>

    <modules>
        <module>ThreadPool-Implementation</module>
        <module>ThreadPool-Evaluator</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**ThreadPool-Implementation**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.intern.multiple_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThreadPool-Maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>ThreadPool-Implementation</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ThreadPool-Implementation </name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

**ThreadPool-Evaluator**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.intern.multiple_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThreadPool-Maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>ThreadPool-Evaluator</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ThreadPool-Evaluation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.intern.multiple_project</groupId>
        <artifactId>ThreadPool-Implementation</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Please guide me how to configure POM, to build Bundle.

Comment: "... ThreadPool-Maven to perform same task" How do you perform the task, "java -jar xxx" or ???

Comment: I just made my projects , now I want to convert these projects into bundles. How can I do that? PLease help

Comment: What do you mean by bundle, jar with all dependencies class ??

Comment: PLugin :- maven-bundle-plugin, is used for that, I don't know how to implement here. I know only this.

Comment: Bundle means collection of classes with their information, just like 
Import-packages, Export-packages, Private-Packages, Bundle-Name, Bundle-SymbolicName, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven bundle plugin is used for generating OSGi compatible bundle JAR files.  Check out the [Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) for more info.